# How to serve a static JS file in SvelteKit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sveltekit

I have a JS file that creates an iframe element and appends it to the body. I am planning on having it be used by other websites as a widget. I have it stored in `src/lib/static/embed.js`. If I am running in dev mode (`yarn dev`) - I can access said script by going to the path name mentioned above. However, if I build this website using `yarn build` - I can no longer access it (it's no where to be found in `build` folder). How can I serve this JS file to the public? Or maybe I am having a wrong approach to begin with?

PS. I am using a node adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SvelteKit has a special [`static` directory](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/project-structure#project-files-static), that serves files as is. It is directly at the root (not within `src`).

You could place your file there, note that you could run into caching/versioning issues if you just use `/embed.js` as the path. Also, the file is not not built, so you cannot import e.g. components, as that would require the Svelte compiler to process the file.

You might want to just add a regular `/embed` route instead. To not have it a apply the default layout, you can create a group and put everything else in there ([see docs on this](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts-breaking-out-of-layouts)).

Comment: Thanks, this worked great for me! I somehow missed information about the 'static' directory